# Access field in multilanguage

Tags: grails, gsp, grails-2.0

I have a simple domain something like this:

```
class Family {
    String name_en
    String name_fr
}
```

In a controller I retrieve all the records in that domain with an executiveQuery like this:

```
   def family =Family.executeQuery("select new Map(name_en as name_en, name_fr as name_fr) from Family")
```

I'm simplify the actual code for the sake of clarity. Then I have a GSP page that show this data, but I want to show based on the language.
So generally I get the language with this code:

```
<g:set var="lang" value="${org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request).getLanguage()}"/>
```

but how can I select the name based on the language, here I got the en

```
 <g:each in="${family}" status="index" var="record">
                       
  ${record?.name_en}

 </g:each>
```

I thought I could do something like this, but of course it doesn't work:

```
${record?.name_`lang`}
```

Comment: ${record?."name_${lang}"} perhaps? Just a thought...

Comment: it works!! thank you!! if you put your comment as answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be easiest to use a dynamically generated property name in this case:

```
${record?."name_${lang}"}
```

One of the great things about GString & Groovy.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a bunch of if-then-else.

```
 <g:each in="${family}" status="index" var="record">
     <g:if test="${lang == 'en'}">
         ${record?.name_en}
     </g:if>
     <g:elseif test="${lang == 'fr'}">
         ${record?.name_fr}
     </g:elseif>
 </g:each>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid unfortunately

Comment: I use a Map in my controller. I don't know how to use Map in a view.  You put the language-name pair in a Map.  And then you can use ```result.familyName[lang]``` to look up the name in English or French.  But you will need to build the Map.  You will have something like this: ```family.familyName['eng'] = 'Joe'; family.familyName['fr'] = 'Jose';``` familyName is a Map.  You declare it like this: ```def familyName = [:]```